# Supress own name in citations for CV

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing my CV, and I would like to use biblatex for my list of publications. However, I want the list to exclude my own name, and include any co-authors in parentheses after the title of the article, like this:

"Paper on topic X", Journal of X, 2001

"Paper on topic Y" (with John Doe), Journal of Y, 2003

I'm sure this is possible, but I'm far from competent enought to figure out how to do it myself.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22135, @PLK's answer can probably be adapted to your desired format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not competent enought to do that. Working from that example, I'm able to change my name into whatever I want, but I can't remove it completely. Furthermore, for papers I authored alone I need to drop the full (with ...)-part.

Comment: You need to combine it with a customization of the author field; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806 for an introduction and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743 for swapping fields. (I'm not expert enough to whip up `biblatex` solution, but I have one using `bibtex` if that is of any help?)

Comment: It would help if you could include a minimal working example in your question -- including which biblatex (bibliography and citation) styles you would like to use -- so people can base their modifications on that.

Comment: The duplicate completely solves my problem. I'll leave this question here so that others might find it easier. Thanks for the help!